# Adding a Layer on the viewed location

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

Actually, I want to vector bend a layer (not properly georeferenced), so it fits in my project.
When I add it in my QGis 3.14, it appears on a very strange location, i.e. its not even on planet earth.
Now, when I try to use vector bending, QGis crashes everytime and I think its happening because of the extreme distance, but I truly dont know about that.
Is there a possibilty to just add the new Layer right on top of my current projectlayers to use vector bending properly?

The first picture is the layer I want to add, the second my actual project. On the bottom you can see the coordinates[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second layer was drawn using EPSG code 5650. You can recognize it because the coordinates are exactly like your "correct" layer, only there's a leading `33`.

How to solve: Load the layer as you did, then go to layer properties -> Source and change the CRS from probably 25833 to 5650.

Note: This is one of the few occurances where it is okay to set the CRS of a layer instead of reprojecting the whole layer.

Comment: Another note on the side. EPSG4647 does the same to coordinates in UTM zone 32N.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Also, no need to even vectorbend!